# Flagging summary improvement: filters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

Here is my flagging summary on SU:

> ```
> Your flagging history
>   32 posts flagged as requiring moderator attention
>
>   2 are waiting for review
>   3 were marked valid
>   1 were marked invalid
>   (older flags were not recorded valid/invalid)
>
>   2 posts marked as spam
> ```

It is **too complicated** to look for invalid flags. Would it be possible to make filters on the top of the page (like on favorites for example) with:

`By date`, `By type` (off-topic, spam, dupes), `By status` (accepted, pending, rejected)

It would make it easier for reviewers to **check their flagging** and eventually know **what to improve on**.

Or is there another easy way to audit this?

Comment: Just keep checking on them every five minutes. Actually, there should be a gold badge for that: Flagging Junkie: Viewed flagging summary more than 100 times on at least 20 days. (Can be awarded multiple times.)

Comment: I suggest these "by status" filters: all, waiting for review, deemed helpful, declined, disputed

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172262/add-a-notification-on-moderator-comments-on-flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of showing individual posts as valid / invalid tends to be an emotive one - with people tending to demand

> why was this flag not marked valid? I DEMAND JUSTICE!

at the moment we'd prefer to avoid this level of focus on individual flags, hence why we don't display this (even though we track it).

If I'm being silly, please do say - but we just don't want to bombard moderators with "EXPLAIN YOURSELF" on what are, very often, pretty subjective calls.

Comment: my idea was that this will help users to improve their flaggings, witch I think would help moderators

Comment: I think indicating to users which of their flags were marked as invalid needs much improvement, right now it's still way too difficult and time-consuming to figure out, and thus what value is it to the flaggers?  I'm not learning how to flag any better if I don't know which flags were invalid.  I won't necessarily bother the moderators about it, I can look back at the original post and figure it out myself, but right now I can't even do that.  It's like there's no point to the flagging summary at all.

Comment: Are you in favor of reviewing the current stand of not allowing to filter flags... I have 26 pages of Flagging history on Ask Ubuntu, so it's not worthwhile to look and search for a couple of declined and disputed flags out of more than 1300 raised from the history manually... [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iAkYC.png)

Comment: Any chance you will reconsider? Especially given some of the delays in handling flags (on SO) and the possibly confusing warning messages about recently declines flags? I could dump a bounty on this. Or start a new request if necessary?

Answer (score 24):

Oded graciously worked on this request along with several other improvements to the flag history page. You are now able to filter your flag history.

Answer (score 4):

I think filters on the flag summary page are an excellent idea, most importantly a filter to show the list of disputed and declined flags. Declined and disputed flags really help users learn which sorts of flags are acceptable and which are not. For instance, consider my flagging history on Stack Overflow:

- 7 helpful flags for every declined/disputed flag among my first 25 flags
- 24 helpful flags for every declined/disputed flag among my next 25 flags
- 220 helpful flags for every declined/disputed flag among my next 3,971 flags

Even thousands of flags in, studying every flagging mistake I've made has helped me drive down my rate of bad flags:

[image]

Unfortunately, the flag summary page makes it really challenging to find your declined and disputed flags both because pages are short (so you may need to go through many pages to find all the bad flags) and because there is no way to separate between helpful and bad flags so you need to do a text search on every page. A filter would alleviate all the clicking and searching.

The currently accepted answer on this question states that filters are a bad idea because they may lead to users complaining about declined flags to moderators. However, I think there's [ample evidence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declined-flags) that users will bring up declined flags on meta anyways [across](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-flag) [SE](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/flagging) [sites](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/tagged/flagging), and it's not clear to me this would create a huge increase in meta discussion of disputed/declined flags. I think creating a filter for declined/disputed flags would be of great help both to users with many flags looking to improve their flagging accuracy and [to users with many bad flags who need to review their previous flagging choices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/253560), and I hope it will get implemented!