# Flagging Summary categories/tabs

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flagging summary improvement : filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters)

I think it would be great to have tabs on the "flagging summary" page, like this:

[image: flagging summary tabs]

At least users will be able to see which of their flags were marked as invalid and they could learn which flags were accepted and which were not.

Comment: I've already posted that in : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters

Comment: added my answer to the above: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters