# Flag summary improvements

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

I already read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters), but it is almost two years old. Maybe now is the time.

To access the flag summary I usually:

- access the profile
- expand the profile info (I know my bio, so it is usually collapsed)
- click a very tiny link (i.e. the number of raised flags)

Ok, now the page shows a very long list of flagged questions, without any possibility to filter or to sort.

So I suggest a couple of possible improvement for the flag summary.

- Why not to move it to the user profile's tabs?
- Hence, why not to enable filters on it (`type`, `newest`, etc), just as in the other tabs?

Comment: Any reason in particular why? No convincing argument? Not even any possible benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the reason behind this not being done is due to whining. In the era of displayed flag weight, folks used to whine a lot about declined flags.

While I [do feel that users should come to know of *some* decline messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag), I don't think that there's any real need for such an improvement in the ability to keep track of flags. Elevating it to the "tab" status gives it unnecessary importance, IMO.