# Add filters to the flagging history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history, filtering

So nowadays we have this beautiful flagging statistics page `http://site.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/my-user-id`.

It has a nice statistics sidebar, for which I propose to make the specifications clickable:

[image]

Clicking one of the entries should filter the list of flags accordingly. This can make it easier to track flags deemed important (e.g. custom ones) among the sea of standard "obsolete comment" flags.

---

NB. I know that this was [asked in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92484/222340), but 2011 predates the current flag summary page, so it seemed valid to file a new request.

As to the reason given there (emotions over declined flags and all that), I contend that it will in most cases be beneficial to have someone note their flag has been declined, possibly with a personal moderator message, as this should improve their future flagging behaviour.

Comment: The userscript there is pretty good :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It works fine, thanks :). To make it easier to locate, I've added a suggested edit to add the [tag:flag-history] tag, which is very relevant (probably tag creation postdates that thread).