# Add a time-based filter option for flagging history stats

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags

**TL;DR: I'm proposing the addition of a time-based filter to the Flag Summary page so that I can display the stats for just the most recent flags I've raised (say, in the last month) and thus *review at a glance* what the outcomes were.**

The Flag Summary page provides a useful tool for a user to review what has happened with the flags they've raised, and especially to check whether they're flagging items incorrectly (e.g. flag declined by moderator) or perhaps not adequately explaining the reason for the flag via a comment (e.g. flag aged away because no one else saw the problem), or flagging correctly but choosing the wrong reason (e.g. flag aged away because the post was deleted for a more popular reason — say, "unclear" instead of "POB").

[For those who're not sure what I'm referring to, you access your Flag Summary via your profile page, selecting the "Activity" tab then clicking on the words "helpful flags" as shown in the following image...

[image]

... which then brings up a page with the questions you've flagged, listed on the LH side, and a sidebar on the RH side showing the stats for each category and sub-category of flag. Rather than scrolling through every flagged question, you can click on a selected statistic to just show the questions you've flagged in that specific category or sub-category. My own Flagging History sidebar is shown below.]

[image]

Over time, and regularly reviewing my flag history, I've got better at making my flags more effective. With over 1200 flags in my history, the key thing I look for now is a change to the stats for "declined" and "disputed". However, my flagging history includes *all flags ever declined or disputed*, including some that were simple newbie mistakes a long time ago.

In fact, I realised I would really welcome (and I'm therefore proposing) an option that allows me to choose a *timeframe* for my displayed flag history - e.g. {week / month / quarter / year / all}, the same as is available via the Users menu item when looking at reputation, voting and editing (see the next image). ***In other words, a time-based filter***.

[image]

Adding this functionality would greatly assist me (and presumably other users) to monitor the effectiveness of my flagging. Without this functionality, I have to manually click on the relevant subcategory filter in each flagging category in succession to see whether there's been a recent change to my flagging history. Being able to select a time filter and quickly glance at what's happened to the flags I've raised *just in the last month/quarter* would be so much more useful - and would encourage me to check my flagging history more often!

Related but not a duplicate -
[Add filters to the flagging history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258079/add-filters-to-the-flagging-history) 
[Categorized views in past flags (helpful/declined/disputed)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171720/categorized-views-in-past-flags-helpful-declined-disputed)

Comment: It's already sorted by order. What's the point of filtering? Just scroll down as far as you like.

Comment: @CodyGray: Scrolling doesn't help with the flag breakdown by outcome. Seems like the OP wants a way to directly check a small table of numbers to see any non-zero counts in certain categories.